# Every time an user adds post his info gets repeated. How do I prevent that?

Tags: python, django

Every time an user adds a new post, country name in user's info get repeated.

For example. Someone from USA adds post, name USA repeated many times.

I tried to use distinct 'country = Post.objects.all().distinct('country')' then I get this error
'DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend'.

my views.py

```
def countries(request):

    country = Post.objects.all().distinct('country')

    context = {
            'posts': country
    }

    return render(request, 'users/countries.html', context)
```

my models.py

```
from PIL import Image
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="First name", max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="First name", max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(verbose_name="Country name", max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name="City name", max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email", max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:blog')


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserRegistrationView, CabinetView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDetailView, PostDeleteView
from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/register/', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/', CabinetView.as_view(), name='cabinet'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/countries/', views.countries, name='countries'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/cities/<int:pk>', views.cities, name='cities'),

]
```

my countries.html

```
{% extends 'shared/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

<div class="content-section p-5 mt-5 pl-4">

<table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-6" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>No: </th>
          <th>Countries: </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

{% for post in posts %}

<table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-6" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
          <td><a href="{% url 'users:cities' post.pk %}">{{ post.country }}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only the list of countries, why don't use `.values()`? I think following code should do the job, if you want *only* the list of countries?

```
countries = Post.objects.values("country").distinct()
```

And the result will be a queryset with dict-like objects, i.e.:

```
[{"country": "USA"}, {"country": "Canada"}, ...]
```

Comment: @mfrackowlak Yes when I do .values("country") it works. But when I do that my url in my html stop working {% url 'users:cities' post.pk %}

Comment: In this case, I'm afraid you'll need to either switch database engine to one supporting `.distinct` with arguments, apply a bit of normalization and move countries to a separate model in your application, or change your endpoint to accept country name (or slug?) instead of id of the post.

Comment: I will try to change database. Because I was using sqlite3 temporarly. What do you suggest, mysql or Postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

I guess You are using SQLite Database. `.distinct()` can't be used with sqlite3 so you will have to switch to something like postgresql to use it or modify your query.

so if you can't change your database then just manually filter your database. but think switching to another database would be the best solution to this problem